# INSERT INTO with VALUES and SELECT STATEMENT

Tags: sql, ms-access

Need Assist!
I have 2 tables : `Employee (Per_Code, Per_Name, Dept_Name)` | `Task (Dest_ID, Destination, Salary)` as Data Source.
Now I make another table `Employee_Salary (Per_Code, Per_Name, Dept_Name, Dest_ID, Destination, Date, Duration, Salary)`.

My SQL Statement :

```
INSERT INTO Employee_Salary (Per_Code, Per_Name, Dept_Name, Dest_ID, Destination, Date, Duration, Salary) 
VALUES (
'1001', 
(SELECT Per_Name FROM Employee WHERE Per_Code=1001), 
(SELECT Dept_Name FROM Employee WHERE Per_Code=1001), 
(SELECT Dest_ID FROM Task WHERE Destination="CityA"), 
'CityA', 
'2014-07-07', 
'3', 
(SELECT Salary FROM Task WHERE Destination="CityA")
);
```

But it said "Query Input Must Contain At Least One Table Or Query". Is my SQL Statement is wrong? Please help me ... Anyone!

Comment: Is any of the inner query returning a `null` value?

Comment: Just showing error message. When I checked to the table, nothing is insert.

Comment: Try to use hard-coded values in the query rather than `SELECT` and check if it works and then execute the inner `SELECT` statements individually to see if any one of them returns a null value.

Comment: In MS Access, dates should have hash (#), numeric values should not be quoted. Depending where you are working, " quotes are fine. You should use parameters.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

May be Something Like this

```
INSERT INTO Employee_Salary 
       (Per_Code, Per_Name, Dept_Name, Dest_ID, Destination, Date, Duration, Salary) 
SELECT '1001',E.Per_Name,E.Dept_Name,T.Dest_ID,'CityA','2014-07-07','3',T.Salary 
From Employee E CROSS JOIN Task T 
WHERE E.Per_Code=1001 AND T.Destination='CityA'
```

*Or:*

```
INSERT INTO Employee_Salary 
       (Per_Code, Per_Name, Dept_Name, Dest_ID, Destination, Date, Duration, Salary) 
SELECT '1001',E.Per_Name,E.Dept_Name,T.Dest_ID,'CityA','2014-07-07','3',T.Salary 
From Employee E,Task T 
WHERE E.Per_Code=1001 AND T.Destination='CityA'
```

Comment: I try use your second code. It's running, but there's no data insert.

Comment: Does the DataType of Source and Target coulmn match?? First give a try by hardcoding then by column values one by one...!

Comment: Nothing insert because City values on Task Table is not exist yet. Sory my bad. Thank's A lot @Vignesh Kumar

Comment: hi @Vignesh Kumar plz change the double quotes to single quote for 'CityA' :)

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE maybe singlequote to doublequote.

Comment: No! As far as i know string must be enclosed in single quotes! Plz see here:  http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/access-help/access-sql-where-clause-HA010278156.aspx#BM2